# Custom styled checkboxes - problem with my JavaScript logic (an else branch is not getting hit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, checkbox

I'm creating some custom "checkboxes" and what I mean by that is I'm just stylizing label elements and will be positioning the checkbox off the screen.  This is the design/functionality that came in, so I figured I'd give it a go using semantic checkboxes.

What I want is when you click one of these custom "checkboxes" (you're really triggering the stylized label), the "checkbox" should change color and the background div behind all the "checkboxes" should "light up" as well.  I've got all that working.

When you uncheck the "checkboxes", that "checkbox" would unhighlight but you should still get the background div color while you have **any** "checkboxes" checked.  When you uncheck that final "checkbox", it should unhighlight **and** turn off that background div color.  **This is where I'm having problems**.

Best illustrated with an example!

http://jsfiddle.net/xS2JU/

I've got console.log statements and if you watch them, you'll see I'm not executing that 3rd branch when you turn off the last checkbox.  I'm just keeping track of the checked state and using a simple counter to keep track of how many "checkboxes" are checked. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check one checkbox and then uncheck it.  Notice the red border doesn't go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/xS2JU/1/)**

Since this is only doing it `onchange` count would always be at *LEAST* 1, so it was never at 0 thus the 3rd branch was never called. Or a better explanation, if one was unchecked it *HAD* to be checked prior, making count start at 1 on the last call. I just moved your condition inside of the 2nd condition because this is where you uncheck, at that point you see if they all are unchecked.

```
$(function() {
    var $help_choices    = $('#help_choices'),
        count            = 0;

        console.log(count);

    $('input:checkbox', $help_choices).change(function() {
        var checked    = this.checked,
            $label    = $(this).parent();
        if (checked) { //additive checkboxes, check one or multiples
            $help_choices.addClass('help_choices_selected');
            $label.addClass('help_label_selected');
            count++;
            console.log(checked + '  ' + count);
        } else { //subtractive checkboxes, uncheck one or multiples
            count--;
            $label.removeClass('help_label_selected');

           // Put the final check here 
           if(count === 0){
                 $help_choices.removeClass('help_choices_selected');
                $label.removeClass('help_label_selected');
                console.log(checked + '  ' + count + ' 3rd branch');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Also heres a bit shorter code where you dont have to keep track of count, could be optimized further, but basically I just check if any inputs are checked within the parent by getting the length of the `input:checked` on the `#help_choices` element.

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/xS2JU/2/)**

```
$(function() {
    var $help_choices    = $('#help_choices');        

    $('input:checkbox', $help_choices).change(function() {
        var checked    = this.checked,
            $label    = $(this).parent();

        if (checked) { //additive checkboxes, check one or multiples
            $help_choices.addClass('help_choices_selected');
            $label.addClass('help_label_selected');
        } else{ //subtractive checkboxes, uncheck one or multiples
            $label.removeClass('help_label_selected');

            if($('#help_choices input:checked').length === 0){
                $help_choices.removeClass('help_choices_selected');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your assist.  Help me understand one thing.  My console.logs were checking out (to my pea brain :))  If you check one box, then uncheck it, you'll get "false 0" which is what that 3rd branch checks for.

Comment: That's because your log statement is after you decrement the count. Put a log statement _before_ the first if if you want to see in advance what path will be taken.

Comment: But the issue is one HAD to be checked for you to uncheck, so count was at 1 even the last time you unchecked, so it was always greater than 0.

Comment: OK, I think I got it now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when there is exactly one checkbox checked and you uncheck it, it will go down the second branch because `count > 0` (until you decrement it inside that branch), and thus you'll never enter the last branch. Also, you don't really need to test `count >=0` in the first if because (once you get the code working) `count` will always be `>=0`.

Remove the `else` from the third branch and just make it an `if` *inside* the second branch.

```
if (checked) { //additive checkboxes, check one or multiples
  $help_choices.addClass('help_choices_selected');
  $label.addClass('help_label_selected');
  count++;
} else if (!checked && count > 0) { //subtractive checkboxes, uncheck one or multiples
  count--;
  $label.removeClass('help_label_selected');
  if (count == 0)  { //now no checkboxes selected
    $help_choices.removeClass('help_choices_selected');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but help my pea brain out.  If you check the console.logs, it looks like it should work.  If you check, then uncheck one checkbox, the console will report "false 0", which is what my 3rd branch tests for.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now why my count was off.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of incrementing and decrementing the `count` variable inside the if/else conditions. Do it as a first thing in the `change` event handler. It makes your logic very simple.

```
if(checked)
    count++;
else
    count--;
```

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xS2JU/3/)**

Comment: @magenta - Take a look at this answer and demo.

Comment: Yeah, I see how that makes sense now.